# Change PHP Form row value if another row value is not 0 on submit

Tags: php

I have a ticketing system and I have a Ticket Edit form. The rows which are important are these : `Status` Which have these options: `value 0 = Open` `value 1 = close` `value 2 = Checking` `value 3 = deleted`.
And another row is `Staff` Which contains the Staffs of my website which answers the questions. so the `Staff` row have these options: `value 0 = empty` and other values are my Staffs User ID. What I Want to do is when the staff value row changed from `0` which is `none` to anything else , The Status Value automatically change from `Open` to `Checking` Only When the Ticket is Open (`value = 0`).
I've tried this JQuery code:

```
<script>
    $("[name='call_staff']").change( function() {
        if( (this.value) != 0) {
            $("[name='call_status']").val(2);
        } else {
            $("[name='call_status']").val(0);
        }
    }).change();
</script>
```

But the problem is when Staff want to change the Status From `Checking` to `Close` , After Submit , the status value is still `Checking`. I want a PHP code for this thing.

Comment: So what does the PHP code look like? You want to check if the userid is a staff id, then check if status is 0 and update to 2. This is fairly trivial. The use of Javascript should not be required.

Comment: can u give me the php code of what u write?

Comment: Have you tried? What does your attempt look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this by using [$.submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) handler on your form.

Could look somehow like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#YOUR-FORM-ID').submit(function(){
        if (parseInt($('[name="call_staff"]').val()) != 0 && parseInt($('[name="call_status"]').val()) == 0) // we force both values to be integer and do the check
        {
            // now the UID is not 0
            $('[name="call_status"]').val(2);
        }
    });
});
```